# Good but thirsty

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading the novel [Dracula](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17245.Dracula) when I came across the following phrase related to a dish that the narrator wrote in his diary.

> I had for dinner, or rather supper, a chicken done up some way with red pepper, which was very good but thirsty.

Citation - The above is quoted from the mentioned novel as-it-is.

I think it means that the dish made the narrator thirsty. The same seems to be true as per the following story but was just thinking whether it has some other meaning also because I have never seen this usage before.

So is there some other meaning? How can this usage be used in other places?

Comment: In dictionaries, one on the meaning of "thirsty" is causing thirst, as in *Digging is thirsty work.*.

Comment: @Graffito Thanks for sharing that. I checked my Kindle again and "Oxford Dictionary of English" does not have that meaning but "The New Oxford American Dictionary" has that meaning. Perhaps you can make that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Graffito *Thirsty work*, yes, that's a well-used idiom. But have you ever heard anyone say that a dish *was thirsty*? I haven't.

Comment: @WS2 - It's also the first time I hear or read that.

Comment: Agree with @ws2. I presume this is an archaic use. I would say the dish "made me thirsty" rather than was thirsty.

Comment: Sounds less archaic than poetic to me.  A lonely room actually has no emotions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *OED* records the meaning of *thirsty* as "that causes thirst", noting it as "now colloq[quial]" (fasicle *Th-Thyzle* was published in 1912).  The example relevant here is from William Tennant's poem *Anster Fair*, published in 1812:

> Some ply their teeth-arm'd grinding jaws to chew
> The tougher slices
>   of the **thirsty** ham ;

Answer (score 4):

I found a few, very few, somewhat more recent examples of *thirsty* meaning causing thirst or, perhaps in some cases, a meal without much to drink. Here are some examples:

> With a "thirsty" dish like ham, you'll certainly want ice-cold Coca-Cola. [(*Life* magazine, 1958.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=11MEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA51&dq=%22thirsty%20dish%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7q46S14vKAhVGXRoKHfZ6Al0Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22thirsty%20dish%22&f=false)
>
> It was a thirsty meal and there was a good selection of wines and ale. [(John Graham Gillam, *The Crucible: The Story of Joseph Priestley, LL. D., F.R.S.*, 1954.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=UqFaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22thirsty%20meal%22&dq=%22thirsty%20meal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo9rWF24vKAhVFOBoKHVoLDKcQ6AEIJjAD)
>
> It was a very thirsty meal. But when they went to get a drink from the spring, they found out that the rain had washed a lot of mud into it. [(F. W. DeLancey & W. J. Iverson, *Busy Harbors*, 1969.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=hlmyX2J_EWUC&q=%22thirsty%20meal%22&dq=%22thirsty%20meal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo9rWF24vKAhVFOBoKHVoLDKcQ6AEILzAF)

Answer (score 0):

I would take it that the chicken was too dry.  It was overcooked, or it needed a sauce.  The chicken was "thirsty," not the diner.